# Mariadb 10 Throughput bottleneck

Tags: performance, mariadb, throughput

I have a machine Intel Atom C2758 (8Core) with an WD WD500LPLX (7200 RPM 500GB) 2.5" HDD.  OS is Ubuntu 15.10 (kernel 4.2) with MariaDB 10 (default config)

I am insert about 20-30 rows per second (row size 355 bytes).  It looks like the bottleneck is with the HDD IO but the wMB/s is low and utilization is high.
What else could i do to make it take more transactions.

Thank you.

With:

> iostat -m -x 1

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.50    0.00    0.50   12.20    0.00   86.79

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    22.00    0.00   61.00     0.00     0.39    12.98     1.00   15.74    0.00   15.74  16.13  98.40

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.50    0.00    0.00   12.31    0.00   87.19

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    24.00    0.00   68.00     0.00     0.45    13.53     0.99   14.71    0.00   14.71  14.24  96.80

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.75    0.00    0.50   12.31    0.00   86.43

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    27.00    0.00   75.00     0.00     0.48    13.12     1.02   13.71    0.00   13.71  12.91  96.80
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` is too slow?

- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` is faster, but slightly less secure.
- "Batch" the inserts: either `INSERT ... VALUES (...), (...) ...` or use `LOAD DATA`.